# Trying to search and return the webelement

Tags: java, selenium, testng-eclipse

I am trying to search the webelement and trying to return back like in below code. Will it work. I have multiple times after returning it traversing back to first element always. Please help me in this.

```
public obj1 obj2(String Name) 
{
    WebElement ayName = isApplicationList(Name);
    if (ayName.getText().equals(Name)) 
    {
        WebElement edit = driver.findElement(By.name("action_edit_application"));
        click(edit);
        obj1 obj1 = obj3.method(browser, obj1.class);
        return obj1.edit(Name);
    }

    return null;
}

//method2

public WebElement obj2(String displayName) 
{
    WebElement element1 = null;
    WebElement Element = deriver.findElement(By.name("abcjl"));
    List<WebElement> ElementList = Element.findElements(By.tagName("your tagName"));
    for (WebElement sinElement : ElementList) 
    {
        WebElement ayName = ApplicationElement.findElement(By.name("my_name"));
        if (erDisplayName.getText().equals(displayName))
        {
            element1 = erDisplayName;
            return element1;
        }
    }
    return element;
}
```

Comment: please clarify what error you are getting or what result you are expecting?

Comment: Thing is I am searching for an element in the list which is having individual radio buttons for editing. So I have written a method to search, if it is found, then click on radio button for the searched element. As I have returned the webelement, I am trying clicking in the calling method. but it is clicking on the first element radio buttons. How can I click on searched element's radio button

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use **XPath** or **CSS** to find the element you are interested an click on it rather than iterate all the child elements.

This will find the element with name my_name and has visible text as displayName and whose parent element has name abcjl

```
//*[@name='abcjl']//tagName[@name='my_name' and text()='displayName']
```